# Popover not hiding when leaving the textbox in Opera 12

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, opera, popover

I'm using the following script to display popovers on focus with HTML support in Bootstrap 3:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".focus-popover").each(function (index) {
        var showPopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('show');
        };
        var hidePopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        };
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            placement: $(this).attr('data-placement'),
            trigger: 'manual'
        })
        .focus(showPopover)
        .blur(hidePopover);
    })
});
```

However this input ...

```
<input type="date" ID="test2" class="form-control focus-popover" data-original-title="This is my title" data-placement="top" data-container="body" data-content="Click away and see how this will be dismissed.&lt;br /&gt;However, on Opera 12 it will remain."></input>
```

... is somehow bugged in Opera 12. Due the fact the input type is "date" and not "text" it will not hide the popover when leaving the textbox.

Please look at [this Example](http://jsbin.com/zezemizizuvo/1/edit?html,js,console,output) in Opera 12 as well as any other browser.

What can I do to make it work properly?

Comment: input tags can't have content, so you shouldn't have the `</input>`.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't officially support Opera 12, so, good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the date-picker prevents the browser from triggering the blur event once it lost focus by clicking away.

It does triggers the blur event only if you keep tabbing to lost focus or by changing the values by picking a date.

So, basically a workaround could be emulating the blur event by using the click/focus of another element.

## Workaround

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".focus-popover").each(function (index) {
        var showPopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('show');
        };
        var hidePopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        };
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            placement: $(this).attr('data-placement'),
            trigger: 'manual'
        })
        .focus(showPopover)
        .blur(hidePopover);
    })
    // The nasty Opera < 12 "workaround"
    if ( window.opera && +window.opera.version() <= 13 ) {
        var $buggyInput = $("#test2"), // Caching is important!
            buggyInputFocus = false,
            buggyFocus = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if(!buggyInputFocus) {
                    $(this).popover('show');
                    buggyInputFocus = true;
                }
            },
            buggyBlur = function(event) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
                buggyInputFocus = false;
            }
        ;
        // The focus also stop triggering if it was blurred then clicked back, so we added a click. It doesn't run buggyFocus twice since it only execute itself if it hasn't been focused first
        $buggyInput.on({
            "focus": buggyFocus,
            "click": buggyFocus,
            "blur":buggyBlur,
            "change":buggyBlur // On change is also important, you don't want to leave it open when it changes
        })
        // Since it doesn't the blur event, we fake it by capturing focus or click on the html tag
        $("html").on({
            click: function() {
                if ( buggyInputFocus ) $buggyInput.trigger("blur");
            },
            focus: function() {
                if ( buggyInputFocus ) $buggyInput.trigger("blur");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wsq38u3/4/

## EDIT: For more than 1 date input

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".focus-popover").each(function (index) {
        var showPopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('show');
        };
        var hidePopover = function () {
            $(this).popover('hide');
        };
        $(this).popover({
            html: true,
            placement: $(this).attr('data-placement'),
            trigger: 'manual'
        })
        .focus(showPopover)
        .blur(hidePopover);
    })
    // The nasty Opera < 12 "workaround"
    if (window.opera && +window.opera.version() < 13) {
        var $buggyInputs = $(".operaFix"), // Caching is important!
            buggyInputFocus = false,
            buggyInput = {}, // We store an instance of the focused element
            buggyFocus = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                if(!buggyInputFocus) {
                    $(buggyInput).popover('hide');
                    $(this).popover('show');
                    buggyInputFocus = true;
                    buggyInput = $(this);
                }
                else if ($(buggyInput).attr("id") !== $(this).attr("id")){
                   $(buggyInput).trigger("blur")
                }
            },
            buggyBlur = function(event) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
                buggyInputFocus = false;
                buggyInput = {}
            }
        ;
        // The focus also stop triggering if it was blurred then clicked back, so we added a click. It doesn't run buggyFocus twice since it only execute itself if it hasn't been focused first
        $buggyInputs.on({
            "focus": buggyFocus,
            "click": buggyFocus,
            "blur": buggyBlur,
            "change": buggyBlur // On change is also important, you don't want to leave it open when it changes
        })
        // Since it doesn't the blur event, we fake it by capturing focus or click on the html tag
        $("html").on({
            click: function() {
                if (buggyInputFocus) $(buggyInput).trigger("blur");
            },
            focus: function() {
                if (buggyInputFocus) $(buggyInput).trigger("blur");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/xucagomutera/1/edit

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works, as long as I have only one date textbox on my website. Can you make it work with multiple date controls, too? See [this](http://jsbin.com/zezemizizuvo/5/edit?html,js,output) and skip between both date fields to see what I mean.

Comment: There, I edited the response with an alternative for multiple input elements

Comment: It blinks a bit when switching between those date inputs, however it works pretty well and should be enough for Opera 12 users. Thank you so much.